# How to chance the 3 plot axis values for 3D plots?

Tags: plotting

Example : `f[x_, y_] = x^4 - 3*x^2 - 2*y^3 + 3*y + (1/2)*x*y`

With **Plot3D** i add `BoxRatios -> Automatic' but it gives not the right plot i want.

`Plot3D[-3*x^2 + x^4 + 3*y + (x*y)/2 - 2*y^3, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},  BoxRatios -> Automatic]`

How adding x-y-z axis with values ?

Comment: Perhaps look at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html and click on the orange Details for more information. Then look at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html and click on the orange Details and Options to see how to give Plot3D information about what axis value ranges to use

Comment: Bill, thanks it solved my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Automatic you can use {1,1,1} for `BoxRatios`

```
Plot3D[-3*x^2 + x^4 + 3*y + (x*y)/2 - 2*y^3, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks , with this better explaining i understood it now !